# How do you tell when a phrasal verb ends with a preposition?

Tags: prepositions, verbs, phrasal-verbs

For example:

1. I **looked up** the word in the dictionary.

I understand that "up" isn't a preposition, but what is the procedure to determine whether a phrasal verb ends in a preposition?

Comment: "Up" is also a preposition

Comment: Why is it important to know when a phrasal verb ends in a preposition? It nearly always does anyway, and phrasal verbs need to be learnt as a unit, not in separate bits.

Comment: I was confused because according to Wikipedia: "There are at least three main types of phrasal verb constructions depending on whether the verb combines with a preposition, a particle, or both."

Comment: Oh my God, I think I understand now. If an object follows the phrasal verb, the last word in the phrasal verb is a preposition. For example, "with" in "He put up with his annoying in-laws". Am I correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb#Terminology if it is this section that confuses you, take comfort in knowing it *is* confusing, and knowing the difference between a normal verb + adverb, or verb + preposition/particle is suited better  to the world of linguistics.

Comment: *If an object follows the phrasal verb, the last word in the phrasal verb is a preposition* Possibly, there might be exceptions though. What about the "particles"?

Comment: I'm not sure about "particles", but I think my earlier statement is accurate. I haven't seen anything about exceptions on wikipedia so far. Hopefully, I'll be able to put phrasal verbs behind me.

Comment: @Joshua “I looked up the answer.”  The answer is the object, but “up the answer” is meaningless (unless madeira is involved).  *up* is not a preposition here.

Comment: I appreciate you for responding to me but I have a question: do you think it is necessary to teach students about phrasal verbs? I've checked multiple sites and many of them contradict each other.